# cftransaction and cfincludes

Tags: coldfusion, transactions

I have a question regarding the cftransaction tag.
I have a file as follow... let's call it act_update:

```
<cfif request.before>
    <cfinclude template="act_before.cfm">
</cfif>

<!--- Here I have a lot of thing to update the core table --->

<cfif request.after>
    <cfinclude template="act_after.cfm">
</cfif>
```

I may not touch this file because it is used also by other applications, but I have the hands on the two includes...
In the first include (the before) I putted:

```
<cftransaction action="begin" />
```

In the second include (the after) I putted the rest of the transaction:

```
<cftry>
    <!--- Update here for another table --->
    <cfcatch>
        <cftransaction action="rollback" />
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
<cftransaction action="commit">
```

I made an error in the update of the latest table to test this, and I see that no rollback is done :(

Is there a solution for this ?
Thank you in advance,

Michel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do.  CFTRANSACTION has two different functions.

Firstly, to make some DB code transactional, one needs to put it in a transaction block.  This "wraps" the code that is transactional, eg:

```
<cftransaction>
    <!--- your DB code here --->
</cftransaction>
```

To make something transactional, one NEEDS to do that.

Once that's in place, one can perform actions on the transaction such as commit, rollback, and setting save points.  However these need to be in the main CFTRANSACTION block.

What you will need to do is wrap your call to act_update.cfm in CFTRANSACTION tags, and do your transaction control at that level.

This is, btw, all in the docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c6b.html

The examples are not as clear or complete as they should be, but if you read the whole thing, it's covered.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction... In fact the transaction tags are in the two includes, and the includes are in act_update... When you looks at source code in the browser, act_update and his includes should be in one page code, so that, in my logic, it should work in includes as it works in the main page ?

Comment: No, that's not how it works.  For two reasons.
a) you don't have a <cftransation></cftransaction> BLOCK in any of that code you posted.  It needs to be a pair of tags, surrounding the DB code.  You do not have a block, you just have three separate tags.

b) CF templates are separate compilation units; each file (file, not request) is compiled separately, so each file needs to be syntactically complete.  So one cannot open a transaction block in one file, and close it in another file, because that would leave each file syntactically invalid, so they won't compile. [TBC]

Comment: [cont'ed] CFINCLUDE is not like a way to "copy and paste" code from one file into another file.  That's not how it works.

You need to do it the way I said / the way the docs say.

Comment: Thank you for this explaination. I decided to develop this in another way. Most of the updates were made in the second include, so I make there one transaction block which works perfectly, and then in the cfcatch I set back the fields of the table updated in the main file to their former values... It is a "manual" rollback as I can not include this in the transaction... Hope you understand my english from Belgium... :) Have a nice day

Comment: Your written English is fine, Michel.  Better than a lot of native-speakers I have to deal with ;-)